# query by example result caching using spring boot 2 hibernate 5

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, query-cache, hibernate-cache

I have a table with lot of columns (almost 70) and rows (1.4 Million). However the data gets updated very rarely.
I want to cache the table entities for faster queries. Queries can be of any combination of filter on one or multiple of the columns (Query by example available in Spring data repository).

Would L2 cache with Query cache be a good fit for this scenario? (L2 cache applicable when loading by Primary key and Query cache applicable with loading by Query by example)